# Toggle Other Elements in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a navbar in VueJS where I toggle on or off drop-down menus.  I have no problem toggling an individual drop-down menu, but I cannot figure out how to handle multiple-drop down menus so that if I open up one menu the other ones will automatically close.

For instance, let's take a look at the following code:

```
// template
<button @click="isMenuOneOpen = !isMenuOneOpen">Menu One<button>
<button @click="isMenuTwoOpen = !isMenuTwoOpen">Menu Two<button>
<button @click="isMenuThreeOpen = !isMenuThreeOpen">Menu Three<button>
<button @click="isMenuFourOpen = !isMenuFourOpen">Menu Four<button>
...

// script --> data
isMenuOneOpen: false,
isMenuTwoOpen: false,
isMenuThreeOpen: false,
isMenuFourOpen: false,
```

Let's say I click on menu one and then click on menu two (and then three and four).  With my current code, all four menus will be open.  What I want, though, is that if I click on a particular menu, not only will it open up but the other drop-down menus will close.

How can I do this using VueJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code. But the problem here is that, once you disable the button, you won't be able to click it. Maybe add a checkbox to enable all buttons?

Here's the html:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    
    <div v-for="button in buttons">
      <button @click="updateMenu(button.name)" :disabled='button.isDisabled'>{{ button.name }}</button>
    </div>
  
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    buttons: [{name: "menu one", isDisabled: false}, {name: "menu two", isDisabled: false}, {name: "menu three", isDisabled: false}, {name: "menu four", isDisabled: false}]
  }),
  methods: {
    updateMenu: function (name) {
      const button = this.buttons.find(b => b.name === name);
      button.isDisabled = false;
      
      const toDisableButtons = this.buttons.filter(b => b.name != name);
      
      toDisableButtons.forEach(function(item) {
        item.isDisabled = true;
      });
    }
  }
});
```